# pandas applying a function across rows - mysterious handling of dimensions:

Tags: pandas, scipy

I want to correlate a simple numpy.array y created  from a list with each row of a pandas data.frame. I would like to use scipy.stats correlation functions. (I am aware pandas dataframe has its own functions)

I wrote the following function that works fine if x and y are numpy arrays.

import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   from scipy import stats

```
def allcors(x,y):
 try:
    len(x)==len(y)

    defined = (~np.isnan(x)*~np.isnan(y))
    x=x[defined]
    y=y[defined]

    return(stats.pearsonr(x,y))

 except:
    print 'x, y have unequal length'
```

However if I used df.apply(allcors,axis=1,args=(y)) I get the following error
"
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
"
The same error will happen if the applied functions returns just a single value instead of tuple.

I tried to troubleshoot it by simplifying the function and got ti this point

```
def a(x):
 return stats.pearsonr(list(x),list(x))

df.apply(a,axis=1) # df has 30 columns and 10 rows
```

"Shape of passed values is (10, 2), indices imply (10, 30)" which baffles me. Could someone explain me the behaviour and help me to correct the allcors function?

Thank you for a guidance.

Example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([np.array([4.714,  4.514,      4.100,  4.799,   4.791,   4.820,     5.564]),
            np.array([4.719,  4.288,      4.604,  5.532,   4.827,   4.812,     5.577])])

y=np.array([4.714,  4.514,      4.100,  4.799,   4.791,   4.820,     5.564])

df.apply(allcors,axis=1,args=(y))
```

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: df.apply(a, axis=1) works great... It's the allcors that throws error... did your try this: df.apply(allcors, axis=1, args=[y]) ?

Comment: tried, but this does not yield what I want:
the nonsense result is caused by the fact that y=y[defined] is evaluated to [ 4.514  4.514  4.514  4.514  4.514  4.514  4.514] when arugument y is converted to the list